# Следующая запись +1

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
while ($inv= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "

i['запись'] = new Array('".$inv['id']."','".$inv['id_img']."','".$inv['kolovo']."',0,'".$inv['title']."',0,'".$inv['about']."',0,6);

";

}
```

Как сделать чтоб каждая следующая запись было на один больше тоисть:

```
i['1']
i['2']
i['3']
```

...

Comment: Интересная конструкция, в echo вы создаете массив и тут же хотите его вывести на экран.

Сначала нужно создать, а потом выводить. Или выводить данные из базы сразу в цикле, без какого-либо массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fetch($res){
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {$data[] = $row;}
     return $data;
}
// Db connection
$data = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".$_SESSION['username']."' "));

// возможно это и все что вы хотели, но если нет и вы хотели увеличить
// какие либо значения массива -

// array increment
$dataLength = count($data);
for($i=0; $i<$dataLength; ++$i) {
     ++$data[$i]['id']; // например увеличим значение id
}
```

---

PS:учите матчасть, с ней у вас явно не лады...

Comment: Спасибоньки =)